# How to show Company CI icon useing MarkerCluster in Folium

Tags: python, folium

```
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
import folium
from folium.features import CustomIcon
import pandas as pd
import folium.plugins as plug

df = pd.read_excel('store.xlsx')
```

```
df1 = df[['대리점명','Latitude','Longitude']]
df1.rename(columns= {'대리점명':'Store'}, inplace=True)
df1.head()
```

```
x = []
y = []
name = []
for i in range(len(df1['Latitude'])):
    if df['Latitude'][i] == 0.0 or df['Longitude'][i] == 0.0:
        pass
    else:
        name.append(df1['Store'][i])
        x.append(df1['Latitude'][i])
        y.append(df1['Longitude'][i])
print('store_sum: ',len(name))
print('x_sum: ',len(x))
print('y_sum: ',len(y))
```

```
import folium
import folium.plugins as plug
import json

map_store = folium.Map(location=[37.58, 127.0],zoom_start=11.5)

marker_cluster = plug.MarkerCluster().add_to(map_store)

file_name= r'seoul_municipalities_geo.json'
file_name = file_name.replace('\\','/')
with open(file_name, 'rt') as f:
    geo = json.load(f)
    f.close()
folium.GeoJson(geo, name='Store').add_to(map_store)

for i in range(len(x)):

    folium.Marker([x[i],y[i]], popup= name[i], icon=folium.Icon(color='purple', icon='ok-circle')).add_to(marker_cluster)


map_store
```

[image: I want to change purple cheak icon to company ci]

```
sub_df = df

latitude = 37.58
longitude = 127.0

mm = folium.Map(
    location=[latitude, longitude],
    zoom_start=11.5
)

coords = sub_df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']]

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(mm)

for lat, long in zip(coords['Latitude'], coords['Longitude']):
    icon_path = r"hci.png"
    icon = CustomIcon(
        icon_image=icon_path,
        icon_size=(180, 80),
        icon_anchor=(50, 50),
    )
    marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat, long], icon=icon, popup="대리점명")
    mm.add_child(marker)

mm
```

[image: Also this image is directly above code print result? OUt?]

I tried many time But really I cant

And you can't understand my mean about bad English or can't understand my question

please look under url

https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-tesla-superchargers-in-france-8c10894ab3c

This is perfect example I want to mimic like this

Anyway in first image, change purple checkbox Marker to company CI(CI image is in second picuture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that each marker must be set to belong to a marker cluster. Latitude and longitude and store name are created randomly. Also, the logo is a stack overflow logo.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
from folium.features import CustomIcon

df = pd.DataFrame({'Store':name_list,
                   'Latitude': [random.uniform(36.0, 38.0) for _ in range(100)],
                   'Longitude': [random.uniform(126.0, 128.0) for _ in range(100)]})

df.head()
    Store   Latitude    Longitude
0   ocUReOT56a  36.164013   127.045411
1   KbAQtbB5eG  36.534577   127.515191
2   PdiCOLvjC4  36.715178   126.333321
3   eM33oRtVii  37.889212   126.589194
4   nporJ7t4mY  36.604549   127.563762

latitude = 37.58
longitude = 127.0

mm = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=10)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(mm)

for row in df.itertuples():
    icon_path = r"./data/240px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png"
    icon = CustomIcon(icon_image=icon_path, icon_size=(50, 50))
    folium.Marker(location=[row.Latitude, row.Longitude], icon=icon, popup=row.Store).add_to(marker_cluster)

mm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir! and sorry my late comment I just copied your code and made it after I will study by your code really thank you!